# What is the default for FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD?

Tags: performance, jsf, configuration, myfaces, mojarra

In a JSF application, the parameter javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD can be used to enable/disable automatic reloading of XHTML files.

I am currently researching the right configuration for production deployments, and accidentally found out that we currently run with FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD=1 even in production, which is obviously not a good idea.

This lead to the question: What is the default value for this parameter?

Ideally, I'd like to just omit FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD from our production config for simplicity's sake, and hoped it would use a "safe" default value of -1. However, this does not seem to be the case, because without the parameter, refreshing seems to be enabled (with both Mojarra and MyFaces).

I checked the JSF spec, and while it describes the parameter, it does not give a default. Is this a deliberate omission in the spec?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default is implementation dependent.

Given that you're using Mojarra, you can find the default in the [`com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/javax.faces/jsf-impl/2.0.0-RC/com/sun/faces/config/WebConfiguration.java) class:

```
768         FaceletsDefaultRefreshPeriod(
769               "javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD",
770               "2"
771         )
```

*(line numbers are from Mojarra 2.0.0)*

The default is thus `2`. I can't find this in any Mojarra documentation. It might be worth to post an issue report to Mojarra guys to better document it.

MyFaces has according [its documentation](http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/webconfig.html) also a default value of `2`.

---

**Update:** From Mojarra 2.2.11, the default value is set to `-1` if project stage is `Production`. See also [issue 3792](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/3792).

Comment: Yes, this really seems to be an (unfortunate) omission in the spec. Interestingly, there is an open feature request to automatically set the refresh period to -1 in production mode: http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1434 , http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-936 That looks like the best solution (once it goes through).

Comment: @sleske looks like it went through at long lost. See http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-23/#936 :)

Comment: How would you change this value depending the project stage?